# Radiobutton dentro do Popover não fica checado via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, framework, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma tela de consulta onde alimento uma tabela html com os registros do banco de dados. Em uma das colunas, de cada linha, há algumas opções como editar, excluir, add fotos e outra opção que abre o Popover.

Esse Popover é do Bootstrap 3, quando abro o popover de alguma linha mostra 3 radiobuttons e no onclick deles roda um script no banco sem atualizar a página. Eu quero que o radio selecionado fique checado sem ter que atualizar a página, porém não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
<td class="col-small center">
<div class="action-buttons">                                    
<a class="popover-dw" href="#" data-popover="true">
  <i class="fa fa-cog bigger-130" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
</a>
<div class="popover-content" style="display:none">
  <form class="marcarComoVendidoAlugado">
    <div>
      <p>
        Anúncio: <%=rsAnuncios("id")%>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input <%=checkNone%> type="radio" name="vendidoAlugado" id="none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=none&idInput=none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'none<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> NENHUM
      </p>
      <p>
        <input <%=checkVendido%> type="radio" name="vendidoAlugado" id="marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=vendido&idInput=marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'marcarComoVendido<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> Marcar anúncio como VENDIDO
      </p>
      <p>
        <input <%=checkAlugado%> type="radio" name="vendidoAlugado" id="marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>" onclick="alugadoVendido('src/rotinas/rotinas.asp?acao=Vendido&id=<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>&tipo=alugado&idInput=marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>', 'marcarComoAlugado<%=rsAnuncios("id")%>');" /> Marcar anúncio como ALUGADO
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>  
</div>
</td>
```

E aqui o javascript:

```
function alugadoVendido(url, obj1){
    //$(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").attr("checked", false);
    $(".marcarComoVendidoAlugado").prop("checked", false);
    $("#"+obj1).prop("checked", true);
    window.rotinas.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Pode postar seu código no JSFIDDLE?

Comment: E quanto aos erros no firebug? - Não está lançando nada?

Comment: Está usando algum plugin do tipo "uniform" ou outro que mascare o checkbox? - Este tipo de plugin causa erros deste tipo - http://www.jquerycode.com/theming/uniform-js/